# Неправильный вывод

Tags: c++, c

Данный код выдает неправильный вывод, который выглядит так, будто несколько раз значение переменной выходило за рамки диапазона при заполнении (хотя сам я вводил одни только единицы). Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

#define MONTHS_IN_YEAR 12
#define YEARS 3

    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    char* months[MONTHS_IN_YEAR] = {
        "january",
        "february",
        "march",
        "april",
        "may",
        "june",
        "july",
        "august",
        "september",
        "october",
        "november",
        "december"
    };
    int sales[YEARS][MONTHS_IN_YEAR], years[YEARS] = { 2011, 2012, 2013 }, year_sales[YEARS], sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MONTHS_IN_YEAR; i++)
        for (int n = 0; n < YEARS; n++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the sales on " << months[i] << " of " << years[n] << ": ";
            (cin >> sales[n][i]).get();
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++)
        for (int n = 0; n < MONTHS_IN_YEAR; n++)
            year_sales[i] += sales[i][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++)
        sum += year_sales[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++)
        cout << "In " << years[i] << " " << year_sales[i] << " copies of the book \"C++ for retards\" were saled" << endl;
    cout << "Total sales for " << YEARS << " years: " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

У вас не инициализирован массив `year_sales`, его значения случайны...